# Which double bond will PhMgBr attack and why?

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent, nucleophilicity

[image]

I am confused about which double bond will undergo nucleophilic addition.C=O should undergo but the book says the double bond of the ring.Please tell why

Comment: Which book says this?

Comment: @Waylander Himanshu Pandey Organic Chemistry(Indian Book)

Comment: @OscarLanzi  Interesting argument, except that the reaction gives the 1,2 product (b) as is demonstrated by the references in the answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @PrakritishGhosh  get a better book, this one is wrong.

Comment: So much for that argument.